# Join Found and Not Fund records on same DataResult

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a single table with Id, the thing is that i need to provide N number of Ids (using  WHERE id IN (1,5,101)) but i need to get the same number of records back (if i send 100 ids, i need a DataSet with 100 rows ..) even if Id doesn't exist on this table.

I'm using SQLite so RIGHT JOIN is not an option.

Here is some sample of what i have but cant make it work :S ..

```
SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT r.report_id, r.batch_name, tr.report_id id, tr.batch_name bn
 FROM reports tr
 LEFT OUTER JOIN (  SELECT report_id, batch_name FROM reports
                    WHERE batch_name IN ("L6964498","AAAAAA")) r on r.report_id = tr.report_id) as v 
 LEFT JOIN reports ON v.id = reports.report_id
```

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: I'm having trouble correlating your (1,5,101) with your query

Comment: the (1,5,101) are the ids that i will provide, and they are the IN ("L6964498","AAAAAA") taht i have on the query ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make up a virtual table of batch names using `SELECT .. UNION ALL SELECT ..`.  Then join that to your `reports` table.

```
SELECT tr.batch_name, r.report_id
FROM (SELECT 'L6964498' batch_name UNION ALL
      SELECT 'AAAAAA') tr
LEFT JOIN reports r on r.report_id = tr.report_id
```

If you have 100 items, you will have 99 `UNION ALL`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT r.report_id, r.batch_name, tr.report_id id, tr.batch_name bn
 FROM reports tr
 LEFT OUTER JOIN reports r on r.report_id = tr.report_id and                
 LEFT JOIN reports ON r.id = reports.report_id
where  r.batch_name IN ("L6964498","AAAAAA")
```